# How to use Instagram API to create Android app that displays photos tagged with #selfie and arranges them using the pattern: big, small, small, big

Tags: android, oauth, instagram

I need to develop this app from bottom up. I tried registering for Instagram API but it's asking for something called OAuth. What steps do I need to take to develop this app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need these three things:

- https://github.com/sachin-handiekar/jInstagram to search for Images
- https://github.com/Comcast/FreeFlow For the List
- https://github.com/square/picasso To load the Images

(Note that there are several libraries available for what you want to achieve but these are the best I know)

With the 3 Libraries you can easily stitch an App together. If you need further help with more specific problems create a new Question.

Comment: Thanks but when I try to register for a new client on Instagram website, it asks me for a OAuth redirect_uri. What is it exactly and how do I obtain it?

Comment: You can't google, right? Read this: http://grishma102.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/instagram-api-integration-in-android.html

Comment: I had already seen the above article before. But at step# 3&4, it says "...click on the “Register a New Client” button. 4. Enter the REQUIRED DETAILS and press the register button." The thing is OAuth redirect_uri is a required detail needed at the time of registration and the above article does NOT mention what it is and where to get it from? I tried Googling it but there are no clear instructions. I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: You can leave that blank or enter a dummy URL, since you're using it on client side (app) you don't need a redirect uri

Comment: Actually, Instagram doesn't allow it to be left blank, else I'd have done it a long time ago. Anyway, I entered a dummy URL. I also downloaded the jInstagram library you mentioned. However, Eclipse doesn't allow me to import it. It says no project was found and won't even allow me to import it as either Java or Android code. Any way to import and include it in my project?